# CSS styling not working on early Android within subdomain

Tags: html, css, mobile, subdomain

I've been working on getting a mobile site working for a client, and have encountered an annoying and confusing problem.
I have set all CSS sizes for various elements (divs, images, FONTS) to percentages so it works effectively across devices/screen sizes, and throughout testing it has worked perfectly on all devices (iPhone, and a Galaxy I were tested primarily) within a sub-folder www.think-ins.co.uk/mobile/

Problems occur when I have added the site to the domain we actually want to use, which is m.think-ins.co.uk whereby it still works fine on iPhone and a Galaxy Note, but on the old Galaxy I, the styling breaks and i am left with massive font size - even though the code on both the m.think-ins.co.uk subdomain and the think-ins.co.uk/mobile/ folder version is identical.

Please help, this is very frustrating!!!